# How to allow postfix to parse recipient address with percent signs in them?

Tags: postfix

**I am having a mail delivered to a Postfix mail server.**

- That mail got the following address: `else%2bsomething@domain.com` (It is basically a url encoded version of `else+something@domain.com`, which should be valid by RFC.)
- The sender's mail server is being told to go way with this message: `NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from randostring.outbound.protection.outlook.com[...]: 454 4.7.1 <else%2bsomething@domain.com>: Relay access denied; from=<john.doe@live.com> to=<else%2bsomething@domain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<morerando.outbound.protection.outlook.com>`
- The log tells me: `generic_checks: name=defer_unauth_destination status=2`, which I assume is the problem here.
- I have a MySQL lookup for the `$virtual_alias_domains`, which does not get queried during the time the log message above is created. I think it might be cached for some time, but I could be totally wrong here.

What I have tried:

- Disable/Enable `allow_percent_hack` to see if that is the reason, I get rejected. Nothing changes for either setting.
- Tried to change the `recipient_delimiter` to '%', which did not change anything.

My question: How can I force postfix to deliver this email?
I really do not need a permanent solutions, as I consider this to be an edge case.

Bonus points, if you can explain to me, why this email is not received in the first place, because I really want to know why this is happening. :)

---

Edit #1:

I found a difference in the flags for a working and a non-working message.

- Delivered message: `Flag: 1024`
- Not Delivered message: `Flag: 1026`

By looking at different places in the source code (**Flag definition:** https://github.com/vdukhovni/postfix/blob/bfff4380a3b6fac2513c73531ee3a79212c08660/postfix/src/global/resolve_clnt.h#L36-L37 and **Flag usage:** https://github.com/vdukhovni/postfix/blob/ed3f86da7c3e15cf1ec57241c1f6036d82b790da/postfix/src/trivial-rewrite/resolve.c#L467-L468), I found out, that as soon as there is another `@`, `!`, or `%` in the email address, it sets a `routed` flag, which is then handled later on.

What I have not found out yet is, how can I

a) prevent that from happening

or

b) Hack a little something together to actually route him "back" to my server.

Comment: Is this happening when you send mail locally or only from a specific source?  Email clients should be sending `+` as a literal plus and not URL encoded.

Comment: Yes, they should. But for this question it does not matter where the email is coming from, because we are not investigating the source here. I am searching for a solution on how the destination accepts the email. :)

Comment: Since the % in email addresses was abused for spam delivery at large scale in the past, most mail delivery services today simply don't allows its usage at all. It seems that Outlook.com is one of those services, so either you need to rewrite the address or stop using the % character.

Comment: Maybe a typo in your question, but `else%2something@domain.com` is _not_ a URL encoded version of `else+something@domain.com` as you are missing the `B` in `%2B` (URL encoded `+`). In `else%2something@domain.com`, the `%` is a literal `%` in the local-part (which is strictly valid as far as the RFCs go).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The combination of these two settings does the trick:

```
allow_percent_hack = no
allow_untrusted_routing = yes
```

But be careful! The [Postfix documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#allow_untrusted_routing) warns about the potential for "a nasty open relay loophole" when overriding the default setting of `allow_untrusted_routing`.

Without these settings, Postfix rejects this kind of destination address because the default setting `allow_percent_hack = yes` tells Postfix to support the obsolete source routing mechanism known as "the so-called %-hack", as described in [Section 7 of RFC 1711](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1711#section-7), while the default setting `allow_untrusted_routing = no` tells Postfix to reject source routing from untrusted clients.

In other words, Postfix rejects this kind of destination by default because it thinks `else%2bsomething@domain.com` means "deliver to `else@2bsomething` by way of `domain.com`", but only trusted clients are allowed to do that, due to spammers.

Comment: Works like a charm :). The indepth documentation is great. I did not came across these infos, even though I spent hours reading their doc.